# Properly delete a pointer to a class from the vector

Tags: c++11, pointers, vector, erase

ALL,

```
for( std::map<int, std::vector<Foo *> >::iterator it = fkFields.begin(); it != fkFields.end() && !found; it++ )
{
    for( std::vector<Foo *>::iterator it1 = it->second.begin(); it1 < it->second.end(); ++it1 )
    {
        if( refTableOrig == (*it1)->GetReferencedTableName() )
        {
            found = true;
            delete (*it1);
            (*it1) = NULL;
            it->second.erase( it1 );
        }
    }
    if( found )
        fkFields.erase( it );
}
```

This code above is crashing when there is only 1 element in the std::vector because the code will try to go over the iterator::end().

Also I can't just vector.erase()/vector.remove() because the vector contains pointers and the memory has to be deleted.

So what is the proper way to delete the pointer to the element from the vector.

P.S.: This is different from all other questions since my vector holds pointers and not objects.

TIA!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should check `it1 != it->second.end()`.

Secondly, what is the return value of *vector::erase* ?

> An iterator pointing to the new location of the element that followed the last element erased by the function call.

so you should use this information and rewrite your inner for loop as follows

```
for( std::vector<Foo *>::iterator it1 = it->second.begin(); it1 != it->second.end();  )
 // [1] changed it1 != it->second.end()  [2] removed ++it1
{
    if( refTableOrig == (*it1)->GetReferencedTableName() )
    {
        found = true;
        delete (*it1);
        (*it1) = NULL;
        it1 = it->second.erase( it1 );
    }
    else 
        ++it1;
}
```

Comment: thank you - it works. I just had to fix outer loop as well to break from it after erasing the map element but it is beyond the scope of the current question. ;-)